# How to trigger iframe load event more than once when changing iframe source

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, jquery-events

I have an iframe that links to another internal web application.

There's a side panel with a list of links that changes the `src` of the `iframe`.  Sometimes if there's a lot of data, the `iframe` site takes a while to load.  I want to put a spinner icon when a link is clicked and hide it when the frame is loaded.

I change the src using `$('#myiframe').attr('src', urlVar)` in a click function for the links.  I can show the spinner on click.

The problem is, how do I hide it? How do I find out that the `iframe` has finished loading?

I tried using `$('#myiframe').load(function() { })` but that only works on the initial load (i.e. for the first link I click), not for subsequent loads (if I click on another link).

Answer (score 0):

This javascript works for me :

```
function loadNewUrl (url){

    if(url === undefined) url = 'http://example.com?v=' + Math.random();

    var ifr = document.getElementById('myiframe');

    ifr.setAttribute('src',url);
    ifr.onload = function() {
        alert('loaded');
    };

}
```